# How to replace whitespace in a string when a condition is applied

Tags: python, string, whitespace

My code returns an exception on some test cases and TRUE on other test cases.

**CASE 1:**

sample input:

```
<br>source = 'Delhi'<br>
destination = 'Agra'<br>
Type = 'one-way'
```

Expected output:

```
if exist -> return 'already exist' else: insert into dB.
```

My output:

working correctly

**CASE 2:**

Sample Input:

```
source = 'Delhi'<br>
destination = 'A gra'<br>
Type = 'one-way'<br>
```

Expected output:

```
if exist -> return 'already exist' else: insert into dB.
```

My output:

```
Error: local variable 'source' referenced before assignment
```

If I assign the variable as `None` it will show success which is incorrect.

```
res = db.test("select source,destination,type from cities where source = '"+str(self.source)+"' and destination='"+str(self.destination)+"' and type = '"+str(self.type)+"'")
for row in res:
    source = row['source']
    destination = row['destination']
    types = row['type']
src = self.source
dst = self.destination
typ = self.type
if str(src).replace(' ','').lower() == str(source).replace(' ','').lower() and str(dst).replace(' ','').lower() == str(destination).replace(' ','').lower() and str(typ).replace(' ','').lower() == str(types).replace(' ','').lower():
     return "already exist"
```

Comment: Which exception? How you expect us to help you with the error when you won't give us any information

Comment: Show us a full traceback. Are you sure your indentation is correct? Should the for loop only contain three lines?

Comment: What you called the **sample Input** is the value of `res`? Could you provide it otherwise? Your code is part of a class. Did you test it outside of the class before posting it? You provided the output and a **kind of** input (if `res` is the input, then is it a dictionary, a list, a dictionary in a list? a string?...) but you did not provide the error and a decent piece of code to work with...

Comment: Error: local variable 'source' referenced before assignment
If I assign the variable as None. Then It will show success which is incorrect.

Comment: and Res is just a variable which stores the data which comes after the query executes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize source,destination and type variable outside the  loop to empty string.
You are trying to use a variable "source" which is initialized and then declared in for loop. You must initialize it outside the loop.

If you initialize only "source" outside, you would get the second exception as "local variable 'destination' referenced before assignment."

```
source = ""
destination = ""
types = ""
res = db.test("select source,destination,type from cities where source = '"+str(self.source)+"' and destination='"+str(self.destination)+"' and type = '"+str(self.type)+"'")
for row in res:
    source = row['source']
    destination = row['destination']
    types = row['type']
src = self.source
dst = self.destination
typ = self.type
if str(src).replace(' ','').lower() == str(source).replace(' ','').lower() and str(dst).replace(' ','').lower() == str(destination).replace(' ','').lower() and str(typ).replace(' ','').lower() == str(types).replace(' ','').lower():
     return "already exist"
```

Comment: **Thankz** sir :)

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested please update the post with the stacktrace, or you try to read the error and you will understand by your self. I was not able to spot the error with the code but 2 observations,

1. you are using user input as is while generating a query (Read about SQL Injection) use Query Parameters instead
2. Why are you converting each variable to "str"? by default it should be "str"

I wanted to add this as comment but dont have reps to add comment.

Comment: Error: local variable 'source' referenced before assignment
If I assign the variable as None. Then It will show success which is incorrect.

Comment: I put "str" because when I code in pycharm for this particular code, it does not show replace() without str. I don't know why.

Comment: Python is duck typing so assume that when code is executed it will find replace..  pycharm is not showing because it can not infer type from self.source or others ... You can also check if all the variables are if tyoe str...  isinstance(str, <variable>)